# AbstractWizardFormController backward without validation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

In certain [Spring MVC Handling Multipage Forms tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/)

The example shows that:

- Page1: username (required) - _target0
- Page2: password (required) - _target1
- Page3: remark (required) - _target2

If user goes back from Page2 to Page1 without password input, the target Page1 would show "password required", which indicates Page2's validator has been called even though it is not necessary.

So my question is, how to implement "dirty back without validation"?

According to the api doc, I can use:

```
setAllowDirtyBack()
```

to allow dirty back.

But when it comes to the validation part, seems no direct solution is provided.

My current solution is:

1. extract target page number from parameter name _target* in 
   onBind(HttpServletRequest, Object, Errors)
   According to [Spring's api](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html), onBind allows you to do custom processing after binding but before validation
2. during validatePage(Object command, Errors errors, int page), compare targetPage and page
   If targetPage < page, means user clicks "prev" button, so relevant validation logic can be bypassed.

Please feel free to give me your opinion about this solution.

Thanks in advance.